# Identifying specific set of characters in binary file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, centos, filenames

I am trying to create a bash script which achieves the following tasks:

1. Read a binary file name.
2. Check if input binary file name contains `A1` or `B1` (case insensitive).
3. Depending on the identified string if it contains `A1` copy to `dirA/`, else if contains `B1` copy to `dirB/`.

I currently have task 1 and 2 figured out, but would appreciate some guidance on task 2.

Comment: Why do you want to read the file if you just care about its name?

Comment: hello @MarcusMüller a good question indeed, I just thought I would need to assign the input parameter to a variable before I could identify if it contained `A1` or `B1`. The script would be executed like so: `$ ./script.sh filename.extension`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think you might be confusing "reading in a file" and "reading a file *name*"! But yeah, what you need is nicely illustrated by the answer you've gotten.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for the feedback, I have adjusted my original question based on your comment.

Comment: Looks like it helped Kusalananda tailor his answer closer to your needs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all files in the current directory that contain the substring `A1` in their names to `dirA` (a directory that is assumed to exist), and then copy all files with `B1` in their names to `dirB` in the same way:

```bash
cp ./*A1* dirA/
cp ./*B1* dirB/
```

or, using `--` to delimit command line options from filename operands,

```bash
cp -- *A1* dirA/
cp -- *B1* dirB/
```

This would ignore files with hidden names (names starting with a dot).  If you need to include these, then set the `dotglob` shell option in `bash` with `shopt -s dotglob` before running the commands.

---

Addressing the updated question, which is about a script that receives one or several filenames on its command line and that needs to move them to the correct directory based on their filenames.

You may use `case ... esac` to test whether a given string (filename) matches a pattern and then set the destination directory based on the result of that test.  In the code below, we additionally output a warning message if neither pattern matches:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for filename do
    case $filename in
        *A1*) destdir=dirA ;;
        *B1*) destdir=dirB ;;
        *)
            printf 'Can not sort "%s", skipping it\n' "$filename" >&2
            continue
    esac

    cp -- "$filename" "$destdir"
done
```

Again, it is assumed that the destination directories exist.  If they do not, you may want to create them before the `cp` command, with `mkdir -p -- "$destdir" || exit`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this looks promising.